# How to map a dictionary of date components to a NSDate using RestKit

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I'm using RestKit to process all of my JSON responses.  One of the objects is a date, but instead of using a standard format, it's an object with parameters for day, month and year like this...

```
{
  "date": {
    "day": 30,
    "month": 7,
    "year": 2014
  }
}
```

How can I build a `RKMapping` or  a `RKValueTransformer` that will map this to a `NSDate` object?

Comment: NSDateComponents and NSCalendar.

Comment: I am quite familiar with both `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`.  However, my question is how to set up a `RKMapping` or a `RKValueTransformer` in Restkit.

Comment: Have you tried creating a value transformer for `NSDictionary` to `NSDate`? Alternatively use a custom object that have an `NSDate` accessor method...

Comment: The problem is that I did not know how to create a RKValueTransformer that would do this.  I figured it out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using.

```
RKValueTransformer *dateTransformer = [RKBlockValueTransformer valueTransformerWithValidationBlock:^BOOL(__unsafe_unretained Class sourceClass, __unsafe_unretained Class destinationClass) {
    return ([sourceClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && [destinationClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSDate class]]);
} transformationBlock:^BOOL(id inputValue, __autoreleasing id *outputValue, Class outputValueClass, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
    RKValueTransformerTestInputValueIsKindOfClass(inputValue, [NSDictionary class], error);
    RKValueTransformerTestOutputValueClassIsSubclassOfClass(outputValueClass, [NSDate class], error);
        NSDateComponents *dc = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dc.day = [inputValue[@"day"] integerValue];
    dc.month = [inputValue[@"month"] integerValue];
    dc.year = [inputValue[@"year"] integerValue];
    dc.calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // This step is easy to forget.
    NSDate *aDate = dc.date;
    *outputValue = aDate;

    return YES;
}];
```

And to actually use this transformer...

```
[[RKValueTransformer defaultValueTransformer] addValueTransformer:dateTransformer];
```